# Making value checkbox appear

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a problem with my code. I use CodeIgniter.
I made a checkbox form with a code like this :

```
foreach ($get_student->result_array() as $row) {
  $select_student[$row['student_number']] = $row['student_name'];
  echo form_checkbox($select_student,$student_number,FALSE);
}
```

then the result just like this, only the checkbox appears, the student's name or student number does not appear:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

As per the document,

[Find the CodeIgnitor form_checkbox documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

the array should have an element with key='value'.

Hence this line of code

```
$select_student[$row['student_number']] = $row['student_name'];
```

should be changed to

```
$select_student['value'] = $row['student_number'];
```

Comment: Thank you, now the checkbox has appeared. I am very happy.